# Amazon RDS Strange metrics CPU Credit Balance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have RDS PostgreSQL instance with type db.t2.small . And we have some strange moment with cpu credit balance metrics . 
CPU Credit Usage not growing but balance is down to zero . Anybody know in what could be problem? (RDS instance working fine without any problems). [image]

Comment: This observed behavior could be explained if you stopped the instance and changed its type (i.e. upscale from t2.micro to t2.small). When you do that, credits do not transfer between instance types so you'll have to start over. Could that be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, it looks like CPU credits expire 24 hours after being earned.

> CPUCreditUsage
>
> [T2 instances] The number of CPU credits consumed by the instance. One
>   CPU credit equals one vCPU running at 100% utilization for one minute
>   or an equivalent combination of vCPUs, utilization, and time (for
>   example, one vCPU running at 50% utilization for two minutes or two
>   vCPUs running at 25% utilization for two minutes).
>
> CPU credit metrics are available only at a 5 minute frequency. If you
>   specify a period greater than five minutes, use the Sum statistic
>   instead of the Average statistic.
>
> Units: Count
>
> CPUCreditBalance
>
> [T2 instances] The number of CPU credits available for the instance to
>   burst beyond its base CPU utilization. Credits are stored in the
>   credit balance after they are earned and removed from the credit
>   balance after they expire. **Credits expire 24 hours after they are
>   earned.**
>
> CPU credit metrics are available only at a 5 minute frequency.
>
> Units: Count

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/rds-metricscollected.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when credits expire i will see this metric everyday but i see that metric once. This problem occured once and never repeat and therefore problem not actual but thanks for help

Comment: This doesn't address the issue. Credits expire 24 hours after they are earned but this is on a rolling basis and doesn't explain the sudden drop. A possible explanation: the instance was rebooted or moved to a new instance. When this happens, the credits reset to their initial default level.

Comment: @ijj you have mentioned that this answer does not exactly solve the issue, but as I see, you have marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I am seeing the same behavior with my T2-micro free tier RDS instance.  My hypothesis right now is that the service window is when the instance is getting rebooted or hot swapped, resulting in a new instance with the default baseline number of credits.  This makes Saturday night more appealing than Sunday night in order to be sure by the next business day credits re-accumulate.